# how to commit a dummy revision to the mirror repository?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnsync

If an error occurs, we allowed the sync to continue. 
so, I want to commit a dummy revision to the mirror repository and continue synching.

Any idea how to commit dummy revision to the repository?

Answer (score 0):

You should never commit to mirror repository manually. All commits to the mirror repository should go from svnsync on the master server only. Usually, it's enough to commit to master server to invoke post-commit hook which will run svnsync sync to the mirror repository.

Depending on what you mean by "an error occurs", solution may vary. You should specify your exact case.

Comment: First time in master repository I don't give permission of folder suppose "Test" folder. And start sync operation. It is successfully sync to mirror repository. Second time I gave the permission of "test" folder in master db and start sync operation. The svn throw the error as "Transmitting file data .svnsync: E160013: File not found: transaction '4-e', path '/Test/a.txt'". But I want to when this error will come, I want to continue the sync operation.